# Problem with daemonset creation on kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, daemonset

I am running the following command on the master node, to create a daemonset on a Kubernetes cluster.

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/controllers/daemonset.yaml
```

I  think it got created successfully because the following message is shown,

```
daemonset.apps/fluentd-elasticsearch created
```

But after that when I run,

```
$ kubectl get daemonsets
No resources found in default namespace
```

So I tried to recreate the same but this time it shows,

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/controllers/daemonset.yaml
daemonset.apps/fluentd-elasticsearch unchanged
```

I don’t understand what is happening here. An explanation would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's getting deployed in `kube-system` namespace since the deployment yaml has `namespace: kube-system`

`kubectl get daemonsets` command shows `daemonsets` from `default` namespace and hence it gives `No resources found`

You need to add `-n` parameter in the command to check `daemonsets` created in a specific namespace such as `kube-system`

```
kubectl get daemonsets -n kube-system
```

Answer (score 2):

Run

```
kubectl get daemonsets —all-namespaces -o wide
```

This will give you all the daemon set present on namespace and on worker nodes

Answer (score 1):

When you go to the official kubernetes documentation and check this link [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) you will see the namespace of your DaemonSet.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd-elasticsearch
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: fluentd-elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: fluentd-elasticsearch
    spec:
      tolerations:
      # this toleration is to have the daemonset runnable on master nodes
      # remove it if your masters can't run pods
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: fluentd-elasticsearch
        image: quay.io/fluentd_elasticsearch/fluentd:v2.5.2
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL you used to create a daemonset creates a daemon set in kube-system namespace. Instead of viewing the daemonset in the default name space. Use the below command. It will shows all the daemonset along with the namespace where it is running.

```
Kubectl get ds --all-namespaces
```